# pandas multindex column merge certain columns

Tags: python, pandas

Right now I have a dataframe named result with a multiindex that looks like the below:

```
col1   col2   bad1   bad2  col5
              col3  col4     

value   value value  value  value
```

I would like to merge the first two columns and have been doing so like this:

```
result.columns = [' '.join(col).strip() for col in result.columns.values]
```

The above however returns this

```
col1   col2   bad1 col3   bad2 col4  col5
value  value  value       value      value
```

I would like the ability to pick which index value when I want so it would look more like this

```
col1   col2   col3    bad2    col5
value  value  value   value   value
```

So in the final result, i chose col3 and bad2 to be the column headers for the 3rd and 4th column.

Comment: Try direct indexing: result.columns = [col[0].strip() for col in result.columns.values] # In this example I used index 0.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/8881141), then edit your question accordingly.